# how to get id from sting using mysql function?

Tags: mysql

I want to write a function which return plan code when I give input plan title But my function not working please help me and correct my code. Please find enclosed attachment of error as well. I will be thankful to you.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXN0T.jpg)

```
Plan_code   Plan_title
1           Break First
2           Lunch
3           Dinner
```

```
id  Plan_title  Employee name
1   Break First ABC
2   Lunch       DCF
3   Dinner      GHI
```

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION get_plan_tile_code(Actvi_SubPln_Title VARCHAR)RETURNS INT(99) 
BEGIN
DECLARE ATY_CODE INT(99) DEFAULT"";

  SELECT plan_id  INTO   ATY_CODE
  FROM   tbl_plan_scata
  WHERE  plan_sub_title = Actvi_SubPln_Title;
  
  RETURN ATY_CODE;
  
END //;
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I dont fully understand what you are trying to do. From your description, it seems like you are just trying to accomplish a simple SELECT FROM WHERE, is that true? If so, not sure why you are creating a function to do it.

Comment: 1) The length 99 is wrong for integer datatype. Remove length specification at all. 2) Empty string is wrong default value for integer variable. Set, for example, zero, or (the best) remove it at all. 3) Your query may return more than one row whereas the variable may accept only one single value. Edit the query. 4) VARCHAR needs in length specification, add it.